# In the context of GPU architecture, what does "GPR" stand for?

Tags: gpu

Working with an undisclosed API, I found a function that can set the number of "GPRs" allocated to a different phase of the graphics pipeline.
My guess is that GPR means "General Purpose Register", but I could not find really detailed documentation about their usage in widespread GPUs (also, their number, etc).

Does it mean something else ?

Comment: If API is not specified or else any other reference, its your sole responsible to find it. It gives us no clue.

Comment: You are right, the API is incomplete (that may be one of the reasons why our clients do not want to disclose it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have correctly guessed the meaning of "GPR":

For NVIDIA GPUs, the official source of such information used to be Appendix A to the CUDA Programming Guide. But if you don't feel like downloading a PDF just to look up the number of registers, go to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications) and scroll down to the line "Number of 32-bit registers per multiprocessor".

In CUDA, registers are allocated dynamically. Without going much into details, the less registers your CUDA code needs, the more resident threads you can potentially have per multiprocessor, thus increasing *utilization*.

Comment: _the less registers your CUDA code needs, the more resident threads you can potentially have per multiprocessor, thus increasing utilization._ Thanks for the explanation, it helped me understand the purpose of the function.